# How to generate C++ files for grpc from .proto files on Windows ( cross platform way using CMake)?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, grpc, ninja

I prepare layout for some cross platform project.
One of my CMake files has a def like below:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20)

# Protocol buffer
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(GRPC REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

# Protocol buffer files
set(protoFiles 
    ${ProtoDir}/Common/core_types.proto
    ${ProtoDir}/Cache/data_cache.proto
)

# Private files directory
set(pf "Source")

# Private project files
set(privateFiles
    ${pf}/CacheSvc.h
    ${pf}/CacheSvc.cpp
    ${pf}/main.cpp
)

# Add source files to this project executable.
add_executable (CacheSvc 
    ${privateFiles}
    ${protoFiles}
)

# Libraries to link with
target_link_libraries(CacheSvc
    PRIVATE 
        Common
        DataCache
        protobuf::libprotobuf
        gRPC::grpc
        gRPC::grpc++
)

# protobuf_generate function definition is available under the link below:
# https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/protobuf-config.cmake.in
get_target_property(grpc_cpp_plugin_location gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin LOCATION)

message("grpc_cpp_plugin location is: ${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}")


protobuf_generate(TARGET CacheSvc APPEND_PATH LANGUAGE cpp)
protobuf_generate(TARGET CacheSvc APPEND_PATH LANGUAGE grpc GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}")

# Installation
install(TARGETS CacheSvc)
```

It works fine on Linux, but on Windows I receive such errors:

```
[main] Building folder: Mesh.SaaS 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build p:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows --clean-first
[build] [1/1] Cleaning all built files...
[build] FAILED: clean 
[build] P:\bin\ninja.exe  -t clean 
[build] Cleaning... ninja: error: remove(src/Services/CacheSvc/core_typesprotoc-gen-grpc=P:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe): Invalid argument
[build] ninja: error: remove(src/Services/CacheSvc/data_cacheprotoc-gen-grpc=P:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe): Invalid argument
[build] ninja: error: remove(src/Services/CalculationSvc/core_typesprotoc-gen-grpc=P:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe): Invalid argument
[build] ninja: error: remove(src/Services/CalculationSvc/calculationprotoc-gen-grpc=P:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe): Invalid argument
[build] ninja: error: remove(src/Services/StorageSvc/core_typesprotoc-gen-grpc=P:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe): Invalid argument
[build] ninja: error: remove(src/Services/StorageSvc/storageprotoc-gen-grpc=P:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe): Invalid argument
[build] ninja: error: remove(src/ClientTestApps/CacheSvcClient/core_typesprotoc-gen-grpc=P:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe): Invalid argument
[build] ninja: error: remove(src/ClientTestApps/CacheSvcClient/data_cacheprotoc-gen-grpc=P:/Mesh.SaaS/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe): Invalid argument
[build] 0 files.
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[build] ninja: error: FindFirstFileExA(src/services/cachesvc/core_typesprotoc-gen-grpc=p:/mesh.saas/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc): Incorrect file name
```

A repository with source code showing the issue is here:
https://github.com/stalek71/vs_2019_cmake_issues/tree/grpc_windows_issue

**How to make it working cross platform way?**

Comment: It looks like it is actually the clean command that is failing. Out of curiosity does it build if you remove the `--clean-first` argument? (not that it will address the clean issue)

Comment: No, it can't work with generated files. The message is typically like this one (there are just no any messages from cleanup phase):    
[build] ninja: error: FindFirstFileExA(src/services/cachesvc/core_typesprotoc-gen-grpc=p:/mesh.saas/out/build/x64-windows/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc):  (and so on)